# PLSQL Substitue argument of a function with SELECT statement

Tags: plsql

I would like to display the contents of a BLOB using the functions provided by [Anton Scheffer](https://technology.amis.nl/2013/01/19/read-a-excel-xlsx-with-plsql/) using this query in sql developer: 
**[1.]** `select * from table( as_read_xlsx.read( v_blob ) ); --"v_blob" is a variable containing blob with xlsx` 
but I have BLOB in some other table. To get BLOB i have to use this: 
**[2.]**`select bb from at_table_temp where id_c=4`

So, the question is how to put **[2.]** as an argument to **[1.]**: 
`select * from table( as_read_xlsx.read(`**[2.]**`) );`

I already tried the following but it didn't work:
`select * from table( as_read_xlsx.read( $"`**[2.]**`" ) );`
`select * from table( as_read_xlsx.read( @"`**[2.]**`" ) );`
`select * from table( as_read_xlsx.read( $(`**[2.]**`) ) );`

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: I read plsql a lot of time ago but your query should look somewhat like `SELECT * 
FROM all_tables tabs ( as_read_xlsx.read (v_blob) in select bb from tabs.table_name )where tabs.table_name= at_table_temp AND  id_c=4`, which ofcourse i havent tested and may be syntactically incorrect.I just want to give you the idea.

Comment: Yeah, sth is incorrect it says:  SQL command not properly ended, so sth is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from at_table_temp t cross join table(as_read_xlsx.read(t.bb));
```